# jQuery Class Selectors: With or Without tagname?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a definitive answer to the old question "should i use a tag name when selecting with a class?"

Everywhere i look on the web for jQuery best practices, there is nearly always a point of using jQuery("tag.className"); because this uses getElementByTagName first.

So I've set up a benchmark on jsPerf to check. I've used the source markup from my website so its more of a real world test and run the benchmark on all modern browsers and apart from Chrome and Opera, all the other modern browsers say that jQuery(".className"); is an order of magnitude faster even though this goes against nearly everything i've read in books and tutorials online. I assume its faster because those browsers support getElementByClassName natively.

Here's the benchmark:

http://jsperf.com/length-detection

What do you think is best?

Many thanks

Chris

Comment: Your performance test is misleading. There are no elements matching "p.entry-meta" in your test subject, but there are two matching ".entry-meta". It's not a fair test.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/length-detection/2

Comment: Sorry my mistake will change it. Wasn't meant to troll anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are really after performance, you should not use jQuery at all for querying elements. See this jsperf: http://jsperf.com/jquery-selecting-by-class

There we can talk about "magnitudes". Honestly, without looking into the current jQuery source I can't tell what jQuery does under the hood. Even if it's using `getElementsByClassNames` it will have little and zero effect on overall performance due to all the blood and overhead that comes along jQuery. Anyway, the basic rule for querying elements is simple: *Don't be overspecific*. CSS Selectors work from right to left, so when we have a query like `element.classname`, most engines will first grab all elements with the classname of `classname` and then filter out the nodes which also belong the to element type of `element`.

Comment: It uses `document.querySelectorAll` when it can.

Comment: @Jon which is way slower than gEBI/gEBTN/gEBCN.

Comment: @Jon, @GGG: a quick glance into the source says, at least Sizzle uses `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: @GGG: that is not really true. Check my jsperf with Chrome for instance, `querySelector` is way the fastest method there for me.

Comment: @jAndy did you see my comment on the OP? The test subject was all trolls. There is no p.entry-meta.

Comment: And yeah Sizzle is doing some extra stuff, making smart optimizations... like assuming there's only one body element, etc.

Comment: @GGG: nope I didn't see that indeed. But it still looks like the unspecific call is about 25% faster.

Comment: My apologies, I started the test searching for paragraphs then changed the markup so it was more substantial so I used the homepage of my website, then picked a class and forgot to change the tagname.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. @jAndy, do you think I should use a tag name with class selectors for jQuery? i understand that native JS functions are faster but I'm talking about jQuery selectors.

Thanks again

Comment: @Chris: also using jQuery it's slightly faster to use a tag-less selector. But its really tiny in comparison to the rest (already mentioned that) so it pretty much comes down to personal preference there.